# What is the meaning of the phrase בִּזְכוּת תְּפִלַּת (רַב) רַבִּים?

Tags: tefilla, nusach-sefard

I know this is only in sefard. But I am curious since I have heard two different options for the meaning of this line. The first is "in the merit of the prayer of many" and the second is in the merit of Rav's prayer. (Since Rav was the ammora (/Tanna?) who wrote the prayer (see [Berakhot 16b](https://www.sefaria.org/Berakhot.16b)))

Comment: I'd heard the suggestion that some Siddur had it footnoted as: Brachos, Tefilas Rav ... which was eventually mis-read (reish to zayin) as "Bizchus Tefilas Rabim" as part of the text.

Comment: Yes, I have heard that too. Rav Baruch Epstein says that in his Sefer Baruch Sheamar.